# StaticResource Binding doesn't work as ImageSource

Tags: c#, wpf

If I use this code:

```
<btn:Button ButtonImage="{Binding Path=BtnImage, FallbackValue=../Images/Search.png}"/>
```

my Button has a default image if BtnImage isn't set. When I try to change it into:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ImageSource x:Key="DefaultImage">
            ../Images/Search.png
        </ImageSource>
    </UserControl.Resources>
...

<btn:Button ButtonImage="{Binding Path=BtnImage, FallbackValue={StaticResource DefaultImage}}"/>
```

My default image isn't displayed. I want to understand why and how can I fix this because I am a fan of this StaticResource approach.

Edit:

My used Button is a dummy one:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF_Controls.Controls.Button"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Name="Btn">
    <Button DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Btn}"
            Command="{Binding Path=ButtonCommand}">
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ButtonImage}" />
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

**Solution:**
If I use:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <system:String x:Key="DefaultImage">pack://application:,,,/DK_WPF_Controls;component/Images/Search.png</system:String>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

everything works as expected!

Comment: Maybe the problem is not your fallbackvalue ... Are you sure noting is set to the actual binding value `BtnImage` ? If there is something set your fallbackvalue won't be used

Answer (score 1):

In case there is an "Images" folder in your Visual Studio project, which contains the "Search.png" file, and the file's `Build Action` is set to `Resource`, the following should work:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="DefaultImage" UriSource="/Images/Search.png"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

where

```
UriSource="/Images/Search.png"
```

is a XAML shortcut for a full [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly), i.e.

```
UriSource="pack://application:,,,<assembly name>;component/Images/Search.png"
```

---

Alternatively you can also use implicit conversion from string to `ImageSource` like

```
<ImageSource x:Key="DefaultImage">/Images/Search.png</ImageSource>
```

Comment: Ok, then your image file is not located in a folder `../Image` relative to the current directory of your application. Is it an image resource?

Comment: yes it is and image resoruce and look at my post: If I use "..Images/Search.png" instead of StaticResource everything is fine...

Comment: Where is the resource file located in your Visual Studio project structure? Is there an `Images` folder in your project that contains the png file?

Comment: yes, I have an edit in my post. I think this behaviour comes from my custom button